# Best way to display large text in a table?

Tags: html

[image]

---

I have a table to display/edit the user details of my website. One row for each user. I have a 300-letter comment for each user. But displaying the comment out right takes too much space in a table. I probably need to use javascript to display/hide the comment. The is the best way to display the comment? It need to be editable, so probably has to be an teaxtarea tag.

Note this is a design principle question rather than a technical question. I need to display the large comment section in a professional looking manner.

Comment: I'd use a popup with the textarea, like jQuery.show()/hide() when hovering or clicking a symbol or something on each row...

Comment: @jtheman: So what tag do you put there when page first loads?

Answer (score 5):

First, set the table to take whatever width you give it seriously: set `table-layout:fixed` on the table element.

Then, set a determined width for the "comment" column. The easiest way to do this is with a `<colgroup><col /><col />...</colgroup>` setup (put this before your `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or first `<tr>`, in that order of preference).

As well as setting a width on the "comment" column, add these styles:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This will automatically truncate the text to the correct size for you.

Next you need to be able to show the whole thing. What you could do is have an `onclick` event replace the text with a textarea containing the text. That's simple enough to do, just basic DOM manipulation.

Comment: Hi I have added a screen capture, can you have a look?

Comment: I like this approach.  The only change I made was to use jquery.tooltip to display the data in a tootip when hovered.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have decided to go with a textarea with 3 rows and 300px width and with overflow: auto, so that it is scrollable when the text is larger, but will fit with table nicely.